# Rest API to get information on Vulnerability Information (Exploit Available) from nessus scan

Tags: nessus

I am trying to find a REST API in Nessus to find the Vulnerability Information (Exploit Available)

used https://:8834/scans/(INT)/export 
https://ip:port/tokens/{filetoken}/download
the above 2 api's are working but Vulnerability Information (Exploit Available) can't be found.

I tired POST https://:8834/vulns/export but error is displayed "error": "The requested file was not found"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tenable removed a lot of API functionality from latest Nessus.
The correct URL look like this:

> https://nessus_host:port_if_needed/scans/{scan_id}/hosts/2/plugins/{plugin_id}?limit=2500

To get all the vulnerabilities you need to use another URL call where you can find plugin ids for each vulnerability:

> https://nessus_host:port_if_needed/scans/{scan_id}/hosts/2?limit=2500

If you need more help I can provide java based class developed to bypass Nessus API restrictions. Do not want to publish it since if they see will block it as well.